# Android Как теперь отправлять SMS?

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

Недавно GooglePlay обновил политику и требует либо исключить из приложения разрешения SEND_SMS, CALL_PHONE и т.п., либо сделать приложение, которое пользователи выбирали бы приложением по умолчанию для звонков и SMS, либо подать запрос на рассмотрение приложения на исключения.

Для моих пользователей автоматическая рассылка SMS очень важна. Отправляю с помощью  SmsManager. В списке "исключений", о которых они упоминают не нашел пункта рассылка SMS клиентам или что-то подобное.

Вопрос:

- Как вы поступаете со своими приложениями?
- Может есть альтернативный способ отправки SMS?
- Или все же не стоит беспокоится и просто подать запрос на занесение приложения в "исключения"?

Comment: отправляйте запросы к АПИ и все. Зачем вам SEND_SMS разрешение?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, какое api? Разве приложение может отправлять смс без разрешения? Это было бы очень странно.

Comment: API напишите на отправку смс , и json -ом достучитесь с андроида , в чем проблема ?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, да это понятно, но во-первых оплата перекладывается на разработчика/организатора сервиса, а во-вторых SMS будут отправляться не от конкретного номера, а от уникального имени или других телефонов, что не всем нравится. Если со вторым можно смирится, то первое конечно добавляет хлопот и трат.

Comment: Google, кстати, отказал в исключении. Так что виднеется только использование сторонних сервисов по api. Я был бы рад ошибиться в своих догадках. Как думаете других вариантов нет?

Comment: @SmartDragon недавно интересовался этим... Вариантов нет никаких... С одной стороны правильно сделали. Так что скорее всего нужно делать через API разных сервисов.

Comment: Тоже занят поиском решения. Неужели за год нкто не смог ответить. Если кто-то наешел решение дайте ответ.